# Non-negative supermartingale: What is wrong with this proof?

Tags: martingales

Let $(X_t)$ be a non-negative supermartingale. Then for $s<t$,
$$ E[X_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s] \leq X_s,$$
which can be written as
$$ -X_s \leq E[-X_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s],$$
hence $(-X_t)$ is a submartingale, and thus because the absolute value is convex, also $(|-X_t|)$ is a submartingale. But because $X$ was non-negative, we have $|-X_t| = X_t$, so then we conclude that $(|-X_t|) = (X_t)$ is both a submartingale and a supermartingale, hence a martingale.

This is obviously wrong. But right now I don't see where I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the following result:

> a) Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale and $F$ a convex function such that $F(X_t) \in L^1$ for all $t \geq 0$. Then $(F(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale.
>
> b) Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a **sub**martingale and $F$ an **increasing** convex function such that $F(X_t) \in L^1$ for all $t \geq 0$. Then $(F(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale.

Note that b) requires weaker assumption on the process (martingale property is replaced by submartingale property) but the price which we have to pay is that we need to assume additionally that $F$ is increasing.

Since the modulus $F(x)=|x|$ is clearly not increasing, this means that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ being a submartingale does not imply that $(|X_t|)_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale. An example is for instance the deterministic submartingale $X_t := - \frac{1}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: ahh of course! thank you :)

Comment: @Protawn You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $|-X_t|$ is a submartingale. Think of constant random variables. In that case $(-X_t)$ is  a submartingale iff it is increasing. But that does not imply that $|-X_t|$ is increasing. In fact it is decreasing!.

An increasing convex function of a submartingale is a submartingale. 'Increasing' is essential.

Comment: To use convexity of $|x|$ you need a non-negative submartingale. Here you have a non-positive submartingale.